# Conteúdo do array não está sendo impresso, e sim a referência ao objeto

Tags: java, algoritmo

Olá, estou fazendo um algoritmo que imprime somente os elementos que se repetem, ex: {2,2,3,4,5,5} -> {2,5}
nao sei se meu algoritmo está correto, mas n consigo ver o array propriamente dito, aparece algo tipo [I@71e7a66b. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {1,1,1,3,2,2,7,5,6,14,12,23,3,3,2};
    int[] newArray = new int[array.length];
    int count = 0;
    int position = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if(array[i] == array[j]) {
                count++;
                }
            }
            if(count > 0){
                newArray[position] = array[i];
                position++;
            }
            count = 0;
        }

    System.out.println(newArray);

}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar método `Arrays#toString`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

...

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
```

---

> [Arrays#toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int%5B%5D))
>
> Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array.

Em tradução livre:

> Retorna a representação em string do conteúdo especificado no array.

Answer (score 0):

Você está imprimindo na tela só a referência do newArray com

```
System.out.println(newArray)
```

pois está imprimindo ele e não seus itens, para tal deves usar um método toString, como na reposta acima, ou ainda um `FOR` para cada item do newArray

```
 for(int = 0; i < newArray.lentgh; i++){
    System.out.println(newArray[i]);
}
```